Interpretation of a motion in continuum mechanics with a spatial description
in the book introduction to continuum mechanics 4th edition (Michael Lai, second chapter), there is an exercice about a motion of a continuum (exercice 3.2.1).
the motion is $$x1 = X1 + k.t.X2 ;$$
$$x2 = (1+ k.t)X2$$ and $$x3 = X3$$
the material coordinates are (X1,X2,X3), the spatial coordinates (x1,x2,x3)
the temperature field in spatial coordinates: T = a.(x1+x2)
k,a: constants and t: time.
it is asked to compute the rate of change of temperature for particular material particles and express the answer in a spatial description.
I agree with the answer:
rate of change of temperature: 2.a.k.x2/(1+k.t)
my question is about the physical interpretation of this result. for a spatial description, I look at specific location, stay at it and I look at the value and the variation of the temperature at it.
with the spatial description, the temperature is always constant at a specific location but can change from one location to another but doesn't depend on the time. I agree
-- but I don't understand how is it physically possible that the rate of change of temperature is a function of time! because at a specific location the temperature is always a constant and it is true at any other location. in spatial description, I do not follow a particle along its trajectory --

Please use $ signs to enclose your equations, and prompt the math mode.

We have
$$x_1=X_1+ktX_2,\qquad(1)$$
$$x_2=(1+kt)X_2,\qquad(2)$$
$$T=a(x_1+x_2).\qquad(3)$$
You already have cumputed
$$\frac{dT}{dt}=2akX_2.$$
From (2),
$$X_2=\frac{x_2}{1+kt}.$$
So that,
$$\frac{dT}{dt}=\frac{2akx_2}{1+kt},$$
and You have expressed the rate of temperature on terms of the spatial coordinate $x_2$ and time $t.$ Note that, in this very particular case, the rate of temperature is not function of the spatial variable $x_1.$
